# python ZEEP: GUID not parsed from XML to JSON in SOAP response

Tags: python, parsing, soap, zeep

I am connecting to a SOAP web service using the ZEEP library for python and found that one of the fields that is returned in the XML is not parsed correctly. I have copied the fragment from the XML response below, as well as the parsed JSON.

Also refer to https://gist.github.com/bsteverink/dede1f3341828d069a502f16ccc5da0b for the full demonstration as per instruction in the ZEEP documentation.

I am using Zeep 2.0.0.

The fragment that is returned from the SOAP service:

```
<GetDataExchangeQueryResultRow>
    <DataType>System.Guid</DataType>
    <ReturnObject xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">16fed64c-9b6d-4383-bdd1-fd5cde084afe</ReturnObject>
    <DisplayName>Auto_ID</DisplayName>
</GetDataExchangeQueryResultRow>
```

The JSON result from the client:

```
{
    'DataType': 'System.Guid',
    'ReturnObject': [],
    'DisplayName': 'Auto_ID'
}
```

Any tips, hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of the library pointed out that I needed to update the library to github master.